# Service Reference namespace/contract name issue

Tags: c#, soap

I've created a service reference.  When I try to give it a namespace of ServiceSoap, it generates the namespace as ServiceSoap.ServiceSoap, and, as a result, I get an app.config with this for the client section:

```
<client>
<endpoint address="http://blablabla/_mmwebext/mmwebext.dll?Soap"
  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap"
  contract="ServiceSoap.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap" />
<endpoint address="http://blablabla/_mmwebext/mmwebext.dll?Soap"
  binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap12"
  contract="ServiceSoap.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap12" />
</client>
```

But when I try to instantiate a new ServiceSoapClient object, I'm getting back this error:

"Could not find endpoint element with name 'ServiceSoap' and contract 'ServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element."

That's if I try it specifying the name and endpoint:

```
_mm = new ServiceSoapClient("ServiceSoap", endpoint.AbsoluteUri.ToString());
```

OR if I try it with a parameterless constructor:
    _mm = new ServiceSoapClient();

It seems I need to be able to either: 1) pass in the contract name OR 2) force the service reference to stop adding the ServiceSoap. in front of the name I'm specifying as the name space.  I am not seeing a way to do either of these (the constructor doesn't take a parameter for contract name and I don't see a way to stop the namespace creation from turning ServiceSoap to ServiceSoap.ServiceSoap.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that this line:

[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://menandmice.com/webservices/", ConfigurationName = "ServiceSoap")]

Needed to be changed to:

[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://menandmice.com/webservices/", ConfigurationName = "**ServiceSoap.ServiceSoap**")]

So apparently "ConfigurationName" ACTUALLY means CONTRACT name, or at least needs to match the contract name in the app.config.